# How to get files modified today from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to get files from Azure Blob Storage that are modified everyday. We have a container in Azure which is filled by two Excel files every day, and I need to get those files.

So far, I'm only able to get one file using `latestmodifiedon`. How can I get both files?

```
private static DataSet GetExcelBlobData()
{
    var containerName = "salesbycontract";
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    CloudBlockBlob blockbob = container.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().OrderByDescending(m => m.Properties.LastModified).ToList().First();

    var x = blockbob.Name;
    Console.WriteLine(x);

    DataSet ds;
    using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        blockbob.DownloadToStream(memstream);

        var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(memstream);
        ds = excelReader.AsDataSet();
        excelReader.Close();
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `Where` clauses and compare to `DateTime.Today`:

```
var blockbob = container.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>()
    .Where(m => m.Properties.LastModified.Value.Date == DateTime.Today).ToList().First();
```

---

I added a [working example to my GitHub](https://github.com/mjisaak/azure/tree/master/Storage/AzureStorageExamples/AzureStorageExamples) repository that uses dotnet core with the latest WindowsAzure.Storage SDK:

```
public async Task RetrieveBlobsModifiedTodayAsync()
{
    var container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(_storageAccount.ContainerName);

    BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
    do
    {
        var results = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null, blobContinuationToken);

        var blobs = results.Results.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>()
            .Where(b => b.Properties.LastModified != null && b.Properties.LastModified.Value.Date == DateTime.Today);

        blobContinuationToken = results.ContinuationToken;
        foreach (var item in blobs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Uri);
        }
    } while (blobContinuationToken != null); // Loop while the continuation token is not null. 
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, on your query, how to read the files using excel data reader, and return into list data set ?

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer using the green checkmark and start a new question. Also revert your changes you made to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately this performs the filtering client-side, not server-side. In my case, I have an Azure blob container with 4 million blobs inside of it (using a content-addressable storage scheme, so each blob's name is its hash) - getting a list of all blobs takes about 30 minutes at a time. I'd love it if Azure could do server-side filtering of blobs.

Answer (score 0):

Migrated from [Fikri Hailal's (OP)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5425803/fikri-hailal) November 8, 2018 [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53114584/2) that added an answer to their question:

> Below is the query which work for my case:
>
> ```
> var blockbob = container.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().OrderByDescending(m => m.Properties.LastModified).ToList().Take(2);
> ```

Comment: This involves a ListBlobs(), doesnt it return all the files? What if we have millions of files in the blob?